# Distribution of the maximum of absolute value of multivariate Gaussian

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

I am currently working on some simulations. However, I encounter a statistical problem as following.

Suppose $ 0 < t_1 < t_2 < \dots < t_m < 1 $ and $ B(t) $ denotes Brownian bridge. Let $ {\bf B} = (B(t_1), \dots, B(t_m))' $. Given $ {\bf w}_i = (w_{i1}, \dots, w_{im})' $ for $ i = 1, \dots, L $, what is the distribution of  $\max_{1\leq i \leq L} | {\bf w}_i'  \bf{B}  |$ ?

I think the problem is equivalent to the following.

Suppose we have multivariate normal random vector $(z_1, z_2, \dots z_L)' \sim N({\bf 0}, \Sigma)$. Want to figure out the distribution of  $\max( |z_1|, |z_2|, \dots |z_L| )$.

Could anyone help me out? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x$ being a nonnegative real number you can write $$P\{\max( |z_1|, |z_2|, \dots |z_L| ) \leq x\} = P\{ -x \leq z_1 \leq x, \dots, -x \leq z_L \leq x \}$$

Since we are dealing with a Gaussian vector,
$$P\{ -x \leq z_1 \leq x, \dots, -x \leq z_L \leq x \} = \int_{[-x,x]\times\ldots\times[-x,x]}f_{N(0,\Sigma)}(z)\, dz$$

Here $f_{N(0,\Sigma)}$ is the density of the Gaussian vector you have. Without further information on the covariance matrix $\Sigma$, this is the most specific answer one can give.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you think my original problem, the Brownian Bridge one, is equivalent to the multivariate normal one?

Comment: @simko Yes. It is very easy to construct the covariance matrix in the case of Brownian motion actually: $cov(B_t,B_s) = t\wedge s$.

Comment: My case is Brownian bridge. So the covariance should be $cov(B_t, B_s) =  \min\{t,s\} - ts$. My problem is using L different weighting vectors to combine $B_{t_1}, \dots, B_{t_m}$. Take absolute value of each and pick the maximum one. I tried but cannot work out in simulation.

Comment: I may be wrong but Brownian bridge is still a Brownian motion. Why should the covariance structures be different?

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. The covariance matrix is not a problem. I just want to clarify my understanding. Since I combine the $B_{t_1}, \dots, B_{t_m}$ with L different weights, so ${\bf w}_i' {\bf B}$ for i = 1,2...,L should be correlated normal r.v. And that reduce to the multivariate normal problem. Am I right?

Comment: Yes exactly. Defining $X_i = w_i^{\top}B$, $(X_1,\ldots,X_L)$ is a Gaussian vector again if the vectors $(w_i)$ are linearly independent. Otherwise you end up with a degenerate case. However, I still don't understand the covariance structure of Brownian bridge. I would appreciate it if you could explain it so I learn something as well :)

Comment: You can find the information of brownian bridge in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_bridge  . I think I have the problem of near linearly dependence between the wights. The dimension L is up to 1000.

Comment: That might be a problem in simulations. The covariance matrix would then have singular values close to $0$.

Comment: Yes. So I just wonder my understanding is correct. Coz I am replicating a published academic paper.

Comment: If you think my answer has solved your problem, I would appreciate it if you could accept it.